# HttpResponseMessage.ReadAsStringAsync fails on Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I created a Portable Class Library which is used to communicate with Restful Webservices.
Currently I started to use the Library at a Xamarin Forms Project. While the library is working well on Windows Phone it crashes on Android in this Method:

```
public async Task<WebserviceResponse<T>> Execute()
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await DoRequest();
    var bodyString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); //This call causes a Exception
    var webserviceResponse = new WebserviceResponse<T>();
    webserviceResponse.Data = ParseBody<T>(bodyString);
    webserviceResponse.Links = ParseLinks(bodyString, webserviceResponse.Data);
    return webserviceResponse;
}
```

The call fails with this exception Message:

> System.Net.Http.StreamContent does not contain a definition for
>   ReadAsStringAsync

The App is running with Xamarin.Android 7.0.
In my opinion it seems to be a Bug in Xamarin, but maybe I've done something wrong?

Comment: Are you developing a Xamarin.Android project or a Xamarin.Forms? You only tagged Xamarin.Android for this thread, but base on your discretion, I think it is possible that you're using Xamarin.Forms , but you also said you created a PCL, which should be automatically created when create a Xamarin.Forms solution. Kind of confused right now.

Comment: Alright I'm working with the Xamarin.Froms, but the PCL I'm talking about is independent from the Xamarin Project. I'm just referencing it from the Shared Xamarin Forms Project

Comment: I tested a portable xamarin forms solution with creating a new PCL and reference it from the PCL of portable xamarin forms, it works fine, seems you're working with Shared Xamarin.Forms? Could you please share us a minimal demo to reproduce this is issue?

Comment: Have you tried using the ReadAsStringAsync method on a StreamContent instance?

Comment: Yes, of course, I tested it, works fine.

Comment: I can't reproduce it, when I'm using the HttpClient directly inside the Xamarin Forms Project. I'm, gonna to create a example class Library in which the HttpClient is used, so I'll be able to provide it to you

Comment: It figured out, that the problem was caused by the dynamic keyword, which was used in the PCL. I don't know exactly why but after using var everything works fine